# Regular expression - How to translate it?

Tags: regex

Can you translate something for me? My boyfriend is a programmer and has posted a message that I can't understand at all.

`^((((31\/(0?[13578]|1[02]))|((29|30)\/(0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])))\/(1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})|(29\/0?2\/(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))|(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d$`

What does it mean? Is it a normal message with words or is it some kind of other code?

Comment: You mean he sent an SMS with this?

Comment: It means you need a new boyfriend. :)

Comment: @Ken It means he needs a nerdier girlfriend :)

Comment: Huh... it wasn't even addressed at her... did post as my Skype mood because of my frustration having to debug this regex... she even posted it here at SO... @josh.trow I think she is already nerdy enough :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an expression that attempts to match all valid date/times in `d/m/y H:M:S` format, with or without leading zeros, and using 2- or 4-digit years, including Feb 29 on leap years.  Not sure why he'd be sending you this, unless the context of your conversation makes it relevant somehow.

It'd match:

- the 31st day of January, March, May, July, August, October, or December, or the 29th or 30th days of any month but February, in any year from 1600 to 9999;
- the 29th day of February in any multiple-of-4-but-not-100 year from 1604 to 9996, or multiple-of-400 years from 1600 to 9600;
- or day 1-28 in any month in any year from 1600 to 9999;

plus a time in 24-hour format.

Looks like he didn't account for leap seconds.  Bad boy.

EDIT:

Looking over the regex again, it also looks like it won't match `29/2/00 00:00:00`.  The leap year match for multiple-of-400 years doesn't take 2-digit years into account.  It really can't do so in a way that won't break in 80 years or so (or whenever `00` starts to mean 2100 and not 2000), unless he wants to define `00` as meaning 2000 for the expected life of the software and risk a very subtle Y2.1K bug if it lives that long.

Comment: Wow....Thanks a lot for the help. Im not even sure that I understand correctly your explanation. I mean, I have no idea why he would write this/ it is written in his skype mood/. Perhaps it is something really smart in this type of codes. :D Im sorry, Im just not good at informatics 
But thanks anyway, your answer was really helpful! :)